# Develop a custom Rcpp function to be used with terra::focalCpp to calculate the median of values within a moving window

Tags: c++, r, raster, rcpp, terra

I'm trying to replicate the use of median within R that includes na.rm=TRUE as Rcpp code. I found this really useful link that includes the exact code I need for implementing Rccp median with na.rm=TRUE within my code here: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/424. The median_dbl function from this link works great directly within R but implementing the function within a function I'm using for focalCpp has not worked for me.

Here's some example data

```
nr <- nc <- 50
r <- rast(ncols=nc, nrows=nr, ext= c(0, nc, 0, nr))
values(r) <- rep(c(rep(NA, 10), rep(1, 10), seq(1,8), rep(-999,12), rep(NA,5), rep(1,15),seq(1,8), rep(NA,12), seq(1,20)), 50)
```

Here is my moving window code

```
# moving window matrix 
mat = matrix(1,15,15) # create matrix of 1's that envelopes the extent of the buffer
gr = expand.grid(1:nrow(mat), 1:nrow(mat)) # df of all pairwise values based on row/col index
center = 8 # centroid index of the square grid
gr$dist = sqrt((gr$Var1-center)^2 + (gr$Var2-center)^2) # euclidean distance calucation 
threshold = 200/30 # 200m threshold is converted into number of pixels from center
gr$inside = ifelse(gr$dist < threshold, 1, NA) # if distance is less than threshold, grid value is one, otherwise NA
w = matrix(gr$inside, 15,15)  # Using gr$inside, place indexed values into matrix of original dimensions
```

R function I want to replicate using Rcpp

```
  testFunction = function(x) {
    q=x # make a copy of window matrix
    test.ind = which(q==-999) # find dummy indicies
    q[test.ind] = NA
    median(q, na.rm=T)
  }
```

Here is my Rcpp code with using the median function from the link https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/424

I think there is an issue with having NAs within Rcpp code and running the focalCpp function. When running this function I have this error `Error: [focalCpp] test failed` . Which is not helpful, when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/R/focal.R#L361). The function works if I have an if statement to ignore all of the nas `if (!std::isnan(x[j]))` but this does not create my desired output.

There seems to be some issue with having NAs while calculating by cells within the moving window

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector testFunction (Rcpp::NumericVector x, size_t ni, size_t nw) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector out(ni);
    // loop over cells
    size_t start = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<ni; i++) {
        size_t end = start + nw;
        // compute something for a window
        Rcpp::NumericVector v;
        // loop over the values of a window
        for (size_t j=start; j<end; j++) {
            double q = x[j];
            if (q == -999) {q = NA_REAL;}
            v[j] = q;
        }
        Rcpp::NumericVector v2 = na_omit(v);
        int n = v2.length();
        if(n == 0){
            out[i] = 0;
        }else{
          std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
          if (n % 2 == 0) {
            out[i] = (v2[(n / 2) - 1] + v2[(n / 2)]) / 2;
          } else {
            out[i] = v2[(n / 2)];
          }
        }
        start = end;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

focalCpp function to run Rcpp function

```
  output<- focalCpp(r, w=w, fun=testFunction, fillvalue = 0)
```

Comment: This looks similar to what you asked last time.  Can you add a line or about how this is, or is not, different from your question from June that was also about `terra` and missing values?

Comment: Also in your inner loop `q` appears to be a scalar.  You cannot really compute a median off a single value.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks so much for the help and your thoughtful comments. it's pretty similar but I'm hoping to better understand how to access data outside the inner loop (where my previous question was just taking the sum through the loop) to take the median within the moving window and understand how I can properly use NAs in the way that I'm using them here. I made a couple edits, moving the median outside the inner loop and using push_back to append to NumericVector but this seems to crash my R session when using this on my large SpatRaster

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm still looking for some help on solving this issue. I made a change to calculate the median myself within the function but this still crashes my R session without any error messages provided

Comment: Simplify until it works, then build it up. This works:  `Rcpp::cppFunction("double mymed(NumericVector x) { return median(x); }")`.  Eg it runs `mymed(c(2,3,7))` fine. See why yours crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting simple helped to get to the solution and get past R crashing. The second loop and going from a double to a NumericVector seemed to be the issue. I'm using range instead for the window and that worked for me.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fmediantempC (Rcpp::NumericVector x, size_t ni, size_t nw) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector out(ni);
    // loop over cells
    for (size_t i=0; i<ni; i++) {
        size_t start = i*nw;
        size_t end = start+nw-1;
        Rcpp::NumericVector zw = x[Rcpp::Range(start,end)]; //Current window
        Rcpp::NumericVector v2 = Rcpp::na_omit(zw);
        int n = v2.length();
        if(n == 0){
            out[i] = NA_REAL; //if all NA values then marked as NA
        }else{
          std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
          if (n % 2 == 0) {
            out[i] = (v2[(n / 2) - 1] + v2[(n / 2)]) / 2;
          } else {
            out[i] = v2[(n / 2)];
          }
    
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```